# PHP login gives me a fatal error?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code, but when I try to use it, it gives me an error that says "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_stmt as array". I'm trying to find the username that is attached to the email of whoever tried to log in.

```
            <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        session_start();
        $sql = new mysqli('hostname', 'dbname', 'username', 'password');
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password1'];
        if(empty($email))
        {
            echo "<p>Email cannot be empty.</p>";
        }
        else if(empty($password))
        {
            echo "<p>Password cannot be empty.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            $hashinserted = hash('sha512', $password);
            $db = $sql->prepare("SELECT Email, Password, Username FROM Users WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ? ");
            $db->bind_param('ss', $email, $hashinserted);
            $db->execute();
            $db->bind_result($email, $username, $hashinserted);
            $db->store_result();
            if($db->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
            {
                    $data = $db->fetch_assoc();
                    $username = $data["Username"];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                    header('Location:index.php');
                    exit();
            } //check for results
            else
            {
                echo "Whoops! You entered incorrect log in credentials. Try again.";
            } //end incorrect information else
            $db->close();
            $sql->close();
        } //end login else
    } //end server if

?>
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: It says line 77, but I don't think there is a line 77.

Comment: Sidenote: People tend to call the connection to the database for `$db` and the queries for either `$sql`, `$query` or something else. You name it pretty backwards.

Comment: @moonlightdreamer Ehhh. point to where you _think_ the error is in your code...

Comment: Shot in the dark, do you use `close()` on a query-object?

Comment: Oh, okay. I think it's with the fetch_assoc().

Comment: @OptimusCrime, sorry, but I don't know what a query-object is.

Comment: I really wonder, how many "mysqli login doesn't work" questions has been asked already here. No less a thousand I bet.

Comment: Try $db = $db->get_result();

Comment: @zeflex can you make your mind which one? it's different functions you know.

Comment: `*sigh*`... Guess-driven development at its best: in questions, answers and comments.

Comment: This didn't work either.

Comment: it's actually one of the ways to get it work. Quite redundant with your code though. You still supposed to write the code *consciously* instead of just trying random operators to see if they work or not. If some of them doesn't - they still have to be used anyway, yet there can be *another* error.

Comment: But I still don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @moonlightdreamer Can you post the create table and the html form, I will do some tests on my side.

Comment: **That's why you have to learn first.**

Comment: @YourCommonSense, **that's why the OP is asking a question.** StackOverflow is a site for questions *and answers.* Your responses do nothing to provide an answer. It helps no one when you say "you're doing it wrong," with no constructive suggestions.

Comment: Quite contrary, I made a very constructive suggestion: to learn how to handle mysqli first. StackOverflow is a site for questions and answers but by no means a code review site nor a free coding service. This is no doubts a too localized question, and it have to be closed, not answered.

Answer (score 1):

The order of arguments in your constructor is wrong. The order should be `host`, `user`, `password`, `database`.

```
$sql = new mysqli('hostname', 'dbname', 'username', 'password'); -- WRONG

$sql = new mysqli('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'dbname'); -- RIGHT
```

Prepare() and execute() returns **false** on errors. You should always check the return value for this. For example:

```
$db = $sql->prepare("SELECT Email, Password, Username FROM Users 
    WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ? ");
if ($db === false) {
    trigger_error($sql->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

For fetching rows, you have mixed up two different ways of fetching. You use bind_result(), but then you try to fetch a row of data as an associative array. Use one or the other method of fetching results.

One method is to bind results, and then call fetch():

```
$db->bind_result($email, $username, $hashinserted);
$db->store_result();
...
$db->fetch();
// now $email, $username, $hashinserted have values from the row
```

The alternative way is to call get_result(), which returns a mysqli_result resource. Then call fetch_assoc() on that result resource to get one row.

If you call get_result(), you  *can't* call store_result(). Because you can't call store_result(), you can't use $db->num_rows. You just have to see if fetch_assoc() returns **null** if there are no rows to retrieve.

```
$result = $db->get_result();
if (($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) === null) {
    echo "Whoops! You entered incorrect log in credentials. Try again.";
}
```

My final comment is about your variable naming. There are no hard rules for variable naming of course, but it is conventional to name them according to the following:

```
$db = new mysqli(...); // or $mysqli or $link are also common
$sql = "SELECT ...";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Mixing up these variable names makes your code less readable to other people.